# Suddenly I am getting error on not null able hidden fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My project was working but from tomorrow I am getting required field validation error on the `ModelState.IsValid`

My Model:

```
public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int CategoryParent { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public string CreatedOnString { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

MVC Page:

```
@model LSB.Common.Model.CategoryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Category";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Restaurant/Views/Shared/_RestaurantLayout.cshtml";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("Category", "menu", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CategoryName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First Name", @maxlength = "20" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CategoryName)
        </div>

    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoryId)
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Restaurant")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Category(CategoryModel categoryModel)
        {
            //ModelState.Remove("CategoryId");
            if (!(ModelState.IsValid))
            {
                return View(categoryModel);
            }
        }
```

[Model State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgsKE.png)

Comment: On your view side you have CategoryModel but you are passing RestaurantModel in Controller's Action method that's why the error message. Change your action method's parameters as CategoryModel.

Comment: Do you mean RestaurantModel or CategoryModel? What's the problem?

Comment: sorry that is not the issue. I changed some code for posting

Comment: Your CategoryModel doesn't have 'RestaurantName' field. You are using the wrong Model as parameter in Controller's Action method.

Comment: sorry guys, just updated my question that was just a typo

Comment: @RahulLadwal Where is RestaurantName field in your Model? Show us the exact code "model and view" which you are using. This issue is not conceptual, but specific to your code. How can anyone guide you if code you share here is different than you actually using.

Comment: hi @Sh.Imran above is causing the same problem. I have updated the question. Further, if you need image I can do that also

Comment: Is there no field with name RestaurantName in your model? Did you not have input textbox for this field?

Comment: check the image now.
no there is no name RestaurantName in my model. please review the question again